# jquery validation is not working don't know why

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

please help me to know what is wrong with this code !! 
I searched much but it looks like I have no errors , even that it works when I try less inputs

this is the script code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#patient-form").validate({
        rules:{
            pfname:{
                required:true
            },
            plname:{
                required:true
            },
            pemail:{
                required:true,
                email:true
            },
            ppass:{
                required:true,
                minLength:6
            },
            pcpass:{
                minLength:6,
                equalTo:"#ppass"
            },
            pcity:{
                required:true
            },
            pbirthdate:{
                required:true,  
                dateFormat: true  
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And this is the html code
I use some bootstrap classes but sure they aren't the reason for stopping the validation , I removed the input file and plname and pcity and it was working well , I don't know why it doesn't work really .
I hope somebody help me I need that because I'm working on my graduation project ,I'll be thankful really.

```
   <form id="patient-form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-3" for="pfname">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control sel" name="pfname" id="pfname" placeholder="Enter First Name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-3" for="plname">Last Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="plname" id="plname" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-3" for="pemail">Email</label>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pemail" id="pemail" placeholder="Enter Email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-3" for="ppass">Password</label>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="ppass" id="ppass" placeholder="Enter Password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-3" for="pcpass">Confirm Password</label>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pcpass" id="pcpass" placeholder="Re-enter Password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-3" for="pcity">City</label>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pcity" id="pcity" placeholder="Enter Your City">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-3" for="pbirthdate">Birth Date</label>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9 form-inline">
                <input type="date" name="pbirthdate" id="pbirthdate" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
                    <input type="submit" class="form-control" value="Sign Up">
                    <input type="hidden" name="sign-up-check" value="1">
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: It works fine.  You spelled the `minlength` rule wrong.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/psmdogsn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`minlength` rule is not supposed to be spelled `minLength`.

```
....
ppass: {
    required: true,
    minLength: 6 // <- spelled 'minlength' wrong
},
....
```

Otherwise, it's working:  http://jsfiddle.net/psmdogsn/